# How stop handshake process after leaving empty room in google play services?

Tags: google-play-services, multiplayer

How do I stop connecting to the room after I leave it? Here's a scenario (for example buttonclicker2000 example of google):

Client 1 clicks "quick game" and then clicks the back button - back to menu

Client 2 clicks "quick game" and (!) joins the room. See Client 1 and the game begins. While client 1 does leave room and not want to play.

In the description indicated that Client 1 can start the game, in this case, maybe a handshake process continues to run. But to me it is no longer necessary. e.g. client changed his mind and may want to create another room. How stop handshake process without stopping the Activity? (sorry for my English)

```
log:
client 1

Sign-in succeeded.
onRoomCreated
Leaving room. (here i'am want kill the my room, but how?)
...
onConnectedToRoom  !!!
->nothing

client 2
Sign-in succeeded.
onRoomCreated
onConnectedToRoom.
->game started
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited your post to make it more clear.

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your player becomes disconnected from the game due to network issues you will get a callback onDisconnectedFromRoom.

Your player can (and should) call GamesClient.leaveRoom to inform other players that you have left.

Your player's opponents will get a callback onPeerLeft or onPeerDisconnected, assuming you have implemented the RoomStatusUpdate listener.

More information is at https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#leaving_the_room

and also 
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#detecting_when_a_player_is_disconnected

Comment: I corrected this error. Thanks for pointing the problem.

But testing (not on ButtonClicker2000, but on a real application), discovered the situation when Player 1 leaves the room immediately after the call getGamesClient (). CreateRoom, but until onRoomCreated. So we can not call getGamesClient (). LeaveRoom (this, mRoomId), maybe, we do not have mRoomId. How to correctly handle this situation?

It's pretty easy to play, and eventually the Player 2 sees at in the expectations of players Player 1 with the status Joined. And nothing else happens naturally.

Comment: How are the other players informed about the gamesClient.leaveRoom call with the onPeerLeft() callback, if that disconnected player has network issues, and thus cant send information? I guess onPeersDisconnected() is the way to go